# Typescript - specify type for destructed variable alias

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const {previousValue: prevDate, currentValue: currDate}: SimpleChange = changes.dateFilter;
}
```

In the above code snippet I want to specify type `DateFilter` to the `prevDate` and `currDate` variables. How can I achieve that?
I tried like `<DateFilter>prevDate` and is not working.

Comment: Why not make the `previousValue` property of type `DateFilter`
 in `SimpleChanges` ?

Comment: @adiga `SimpleChanges` class is provided by angular, we don't have control over it

Comment: Isn't `changes.dateFilter` itself not of type `DateFilter`? `prevDate` and `currentValue` get their type from the destructured properties `previousValue` and `currentValue` belonging to `changes.dateFilter`.

Comment: @ford04 `changes` is of type `SimpleChanges` so `changes.dateFilter` becomes of type `SimpleChange` which has properties `previousValue` and `currentValue`. Both of them represent angular `@Input() dateFilter: DateFilter`. But in `ngOnChanges()` when fetched from `changes.dateFilter.previousValue`, the type is not set, we have explicitly set it. Which I can do in multi-line, but wanted to know if possible while de-structuring

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the type :

```
const prevDate: DateFilter = changes.dateFilte.previousValue as DateFilter
```

or :

```
const {previousValue: prevDate, currentValue: currDate} = changes.dateFilter as {previousValue: DateFilter; currentValue: DateFilter };
```